# Finding eigenvalues of the flow Jacobian matrix

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following system of differential equations
\begin{equation}
 \begin{pmatrix}
   \dot{x} \\
   \dot{y}
 \end{pmatrix}
 = 
  \begin{pmatrix}
    -y+x-x^3+xy^2 \\
    x+y-x^2y+y^3
 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
Let $\varphi(t,x,y)$ be the solution to this system such that $\varphi(0,x,y)=(x,y)$. I'm asked to find the eiganvalues of the $2\times2$ matrix:
\begin{equation}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \varphi_x \\
    \varphi_y
 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
at $(2\pi,0,0)$ and $(2\pi,1,0)$ and I have no idea how to proceed. Could anyone point me on the right direction for this computations?

EDIT: Sorry, I wrote the wrong matrix. I need to compute the eigenvalues of the matrix:
\begin{equation}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \varphi_x & \varphi_y
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
In this last expression, $\varphi_x$ and $\varphi_y$ are column vectors, the matrix is written by specifying its columns. If $\varphi = (f,g)$ then $\varphi_x= \begin{pmatrix} f_x \\ g_x \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: It is likely that you copied the wrong problem. It would make sense if you are looking for the Jacobian of the vector field on the right.

Comment: @mrsamy With the last edit, it is the correct problem.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by $\varphi(t,x,y)$ being a solution. Shouldn't the solution be of the form $(x,y)=(f(t),g(t))$ for some function $f$ and $g$?

Comment: $\varphi(t,x,y)$ is a vector valued function, you could say $\varphi(t,x,y)=( \varphi_1(t,x,y),\varphi_2(t,x,y))$. It is a solution in the sense that  $\frac{ \partial \varphi}{ \partial t}(t,x,y)= f( \varphi(t,x,y))$ and $\varphi(0,x,y)=(x,y)$ where $f(x,y)$ is the vector field defining the equation. $\varphi$ takes three arguments, because if you change your initial condition $(x,y)$ you will get a different solution.